# How to get parameters on function on another function?

Tags: python, function, python-3.5

```
def info(name, address):

    name = (input ("Please Enter Your Name : "))
    address = (input ("Please Enter Your Address : "))


    return name
    return address



def userinfo():

    sumom=info(name='', address='')

    print("Thank you for coming Mr. "+sumom)
userinfo()
```

Hello Folks!
 problem is here only "name" is printing but not "address" on userinfo() function, Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Multiple return points in your function will not both be executed. When your function hits the first return point `return name` the method will return and execution of the method's body will be complete. 

To return both items, try something similar to:

    `def names(first, last):
        return (first, last)`

Comment: Done, Thanks...@SeanWhittaker

Answer (score 0):

After `return` statement the program leaves function, so your second `return` is not executed.